# Mount from rc.local fails; how to do it properly?

Tags: boot, command-line, mount, samba, cifs

Here is my current `/etc/rc.local`:

```
#!/bin/sh -e

# Test 1
echo line1 > /home/myHome/rclog.txt

# the mount
mount /mnt/mediaDrive &> /home/myHome/mountlog.txt

# Test 2
echo line2 >> /home/myHome/rclog.txt

exit 0
```

The `/mnt/mediaDrive` is a `noauto` in `fstab`. It is a network share, hence the mount in `rc.local`.

The mount in the above script does not work at boot. After boot, the `rclog.txt` file contains both `line1` and `line2`, and the `mountlog.txt` file is empty. This would indicate that all commands in the script were run successfully, however, the drive is not mounted.

Running `sudo /etc/rc.local` manually in a terminal *does* mount the network share.

There is nothing relevant in `/var/syslog` that I can see, and permissions for `rc.local` are 755. The relevant `fstab` entry:

```
//192.168.1.100/home  /mnt/mediaDrive  cifs  noauto,credentials=/home/myHome/.mediaCredentials,uid=myName,gid=myGroup  0  0
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem must be that at boot time your network isn't available yet, and it's the reason why it mounts *after* boot. You must use another mechanisms to mount the device, like upstart. Example using upstart:

```
# mount CIFS share

start on (local-filesystems and net-device-up IFACE!=lo)
stop on runlevel [!2345]

pre-start script /bin/mount /mnt/mediaDrive
pre-stop script /bin/umount /mnt/mediaDrive
```

You can modify it to suit your needs. The file name must end with `.conf` and saved in the `/etc/init` directory.

Comment: I'll sure give this a try! But I do think it's strange the network is not up at the time `rc.local` is run...

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis you can ping yourself and see ;), change mount by `ping -c2 192.168.1.100` and try.

Comment: I'll try that too. By the way, would it be an idea to use a simple `_netdev` option in `fstab`? My intention is to have several bind mounts to locations on the network drive, so can you use `_netdev` on a bind mount? Never tried that...

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis apparently `_netdev` is ignored in [ubuntu](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2131380) and seems that there are problems in [fedora too](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=280108).

Comment: Yes, that's what I read too, which is what pushed me to the approach I was taking. Nevertheless, the option appears to be working on 13.10 again; see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by Braiam, at the time `rc.local` is run there is no network available for some reason.

This was the original reason I moved to the `noauto` + `rc.local` approach. So, although I'm not quite sure why, this approach is faulty.

In my case, a simple `_netdev` (instead of `noauto`) in `/etc/fstab` did the trick.

Note that in my case, I had several dozen bind mounts to locations on the network drive. Each of these bind mounts also need a `_netdev` option in `/etc/fstab`, next to the `bind` option.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a "sleep 5" above your network command in the rc.local

I had the problem to mount cifs access on my raspberry with osmc, with this 5s the network is up and the mount is OK

Comment: +1, but seems rather more like a workaround than a solution...i.e., it adds an unnecessary 5s to the boot time. And who is to say 5s is enough?

Answer (score 1):

Adding `noauto,x-systemd.automount` to my fstab line is what finally worked for me. I also have a `mount /media/share` line in my rc.local, but I'm not sure if that's important or redundant.

`_netdev` in `/etc/fstab` did not work for me (with or without a mount command in rc.local)