# Ubuntu 16.04 - Second Drive in machine has to be re-shared through GUI at boot

Tags: 16.04, samba, file-sharing, shared-folders, sharing

I have two drives and one of my Linux machines. One smaller SSD that has the operating system and then a larger storage drive.

I’m trying to share the larger storage drive through Nautilis as a Samba share And it seems to work fine but every time I reboot it doesn’t seem to be shared anymore.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rc.local` to add the mount on boot.
You will have a problem only if the network will be init before the `rc.local` will run, and to fix this issue see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/382397/mount-from-rc-local-fails-how-to-do-it-properly)